# Spring dependecy Issue

Tags: java, spring, maven, maven-3

I am getting this error when i open the wsdl url. There are 2 different version of spring jars in the dependency. I want to exclude the 3.0.1 release version. I am not sure which place i need to exclude it. Thanks for your help.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.io.ResourceEditor.<init>(Lorg/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader;)V
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:117)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:528)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:747)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
```

below are the dependecy  i have added in the pom.xml file. erlier i didn't face any issue. I am facing recently when I migrated this code CVS to Git repository

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-M1</version>
                        <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.5.Final</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.5.Final</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.4.Final</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-dao</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.j2ee</groupId>
            <artifactId>j2ee</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Post your pom.xml

Comment: pom.xml, build.gradle or other dependency configuration file.

Comment: added please check

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use two different versions of spring dependencies, espacially if they are major - they are homogenized for a reason. Use the same version for every Spring dependency.

Comment: I have updated the like this spring-orm - 4.2.7.RELEASE, spring-dao- 2.0.8 & spring-jdbc-4.2.7.RELEASE but still same error

Comment: Don't use spring-dao. It hasn't been updated in more than a decade and is deprecated: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-dao-jpa
It probably isn't compatible with newer versions of Spring.

Answer (score -1):

> mvn dependency:tree

might help, since you know which version has to be removed.